# Kivy: adding widgets from another thread

Tags: multithreading, interface, widget, kivy, addition

I've been stuck on this same issue for short of a week now:
the program should add widgets based on a http request. However, that request may take some time depending on user's internet connection, so I decided to thread that request and add a spinner to indicate that something is being done.

Here lies the issue. Some piece of code:

```
@mainthread
def add_w(self, parent, widget):
    parent.add_widget(widget)

def add_course():
        # HTTP Request I mentioned
        course = course_manager.get_course(textfield_text)
        courses_stack_layout = constructor_screen.ids.added_courses_stack_layout

        course_information_widget = CourseInformation(coursename_label=course.name)

        self.add_w(courses_stack_layout, course_information_widget)

        constructor_screen.ids.spinner.active = False
```

add_course is being called from a thread, and spinner.active is being set True before calling this function. Here's the result, *sometimes*: [messed up graphical interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRU8i.png)

I also tried solving this with clock.schedule_once and clock.schedule_interval with a queue. The results were the same. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. The spinner does spin while getting the request, which is great.

Quite frankly, I would've never thought that implementing a spinner would be so hard.

How to implement that spinner? Maybe another alternative to threading? Maybe another alternative to urllib to make a request?

edit: any feedback on how I should've posted this so I can get more help? Is is too long? Maybe I could've been more clear?

Comment: What happens if you do all manipulation i.e. `active = False` in the mainthread?

Comment: might be worth checking out the kivy urlrequest module https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html

Comment: @syntonym Can't see spinner spinning, unfortunately.

active = True -> HTTP Request freezes GUI -> active = False

Comment: @GabrielLins Do the HTTP Request in a seperate thread but set `active = False` in a function with `@Mainthread`

Comment: @syntonym That's a good idea, but code buggs out since we use that HTTP Request result to build widgets, so if we run that request separetly the widget will be built while the request is still not complete - maybe there is a way to build a on_succes around urllib.urlopen, then i'd be able to do what you said

Comment: You can create a function which takes all neccessary parameters, wrap that into @Mainthread and call it from the thread where you do the HTTP request, you like you do with add_widget.

Comment: @PalimPalim Implemented that, but somehow some characters are not recognized with request.result. Any other suggestions? Any hints on why the posted code does not work? I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was simply that widgets must also be created within the mainthread.

Creating another function marqued with @mainthread and calling that from the threaded one solved the issue.

Thanks for those who contributed.